# The [testing] tag - do we need it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The title pretty much says it all. Is the testing tag really necessary here? I think that would be like having a [software-development] tag on StackOverflow.

Is there any benefit to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing) tag has been placed on the blacklist, as well as [quality](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quality), [assurance](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assurance), and [qa](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qa).

Answer (score 6):

My vote is no. It seems redundant. But I suppose we can revisit the question if we find a (relevant) question that we don't know how to tag.

Comment: +1 for agreement